# HttpContext.Current.Session threw an exception of type System.NullReferenceException when calling web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webmethod

I am trying to call a webmethod in Ajax, And I want to get current login user id through session. How ever the HttpContext.Current.Session thrown System.NullReferenceException, how can I get the HttpContext.Current.Session. Here is my code.

```
             function GetReportID() {
                indicatorsIds = getSelectedIndicatorsIDs();
                locationsIds = getSelectedLocationsIDs();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("ChartEdit.aspx/GetIDForDownloadExcel") %>',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ ind: indicatorsIds, loc: locationsIds }),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //alert('Data: ' + data);
                        var data = JSON.parse(data.d)
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(data.ClientID);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        alert(err.Message);
                    }
                });
            }
```

And here is the WebMethod and Code.

```
 public static string GetIDForDownloadExcel(string[] ind, string[] loc)
    {
        ChartEdit cd = new ChartEdit();

        List<string> locationIDs = new List<string>(1024);
        List<string> indicatorIDs = new List<string>(1024);

        Guid clientID = Guid.NewGuid();

        excelData.Ready = 0;

        store.Add(clientID, excelData);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => cd.ExportToExcelDict(locationIDs, indicatorIDs,clientID));
        thread.Start();

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ClientID = clientID, filename = "ExportToExcel" });
    }
```

When it runs to the following code, NullReference Exception is thrown.

```
     public static int GetCurrentUserId()
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session[FujiXerox.Common.Constants.KEY_NAME_CURRENT_USER_ID]);
        }
```

Comment: waht value are you getting for `string str = HttpContext.Current.Session[FujiXerox.Common.Constants.KEY_NAME_CURRENT_USER_ID]`?

Comment: @viveknuna The value is a user id, it could be integer or string.

Comment: Check the request headers from the browser, is the ajax request sending session cookies?